# C# Upload all files from Directory (Compiler Error CS0136)

Tags: c#, file-upload, foreach

sorry for my question, I am a beginner.

I am trying to write a small program that takes all the files on the desktop and uploads them to a server.

Unfortunately I am running into a bug here and don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Here´s my Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace Upload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Username auslesen
            string username = Environment.UserName;
            //Pfad zu Desktop aus ausgelesenem Usernamen
            string path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop";
            //URI zum Server 
            string uriString = "https://webserver.com/test";

            //Alle Dateien auf dem Desktop finden
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
            string str = "";

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = path + "\\" + file.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString, fileName);

            }

        }
        
    }

}
```

apparently i can't upload the files in the foreach loop. (It shows me "Compiler Error CS0136")

Unfortunately I don't know how else to upload the files....

Comment: The code you've posted will give a CS0103 (The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context), not CS0136. Also, it's usually *much* more helpful to us if you include the error text. The error code itself isn't usually as helpful.

Comment: When you have a compiler error, that isn't a bug. That means your code could not be compiled, i.e. it's not valid. This can happen for example if you call a function that doesn't exist or use a variable that you never declared. In Visual Studio you can double click the error and it'll show you exactly what you got wrong. CS0136 means you declared a variable twice using the same name. Change one of them so the names are unique and the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the variable fileName anywhere in your code example above. Could it be you are using the wrong variable in your UploadFile method? You might need to replace it with the variable 'str' which has the file path.

Also you might need to code something in to allow it to wait for file to finish uploading, unless your upload URL can process them in batches or threads.

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong example. In my actual code, the str variable is specified. Nevertheless it comes to an error

Comment: You say, "In my actual code, the _str_ variable is specified". Do you mean the _fileName_ variable is specified? Because in your provided code sample, that is what you're missing.

Comment: You need to provide your actual code, so we can see whats actually happening.